# How to display DataGridViewCell tooltip with title in c++/cli

Tags: .net, datagridview, c++-cli, .net-4.5

I'm using C++/CLI with .net 4.5. I try to display tool tips on `DataGridViewCell` but with **title**. I can easily set the text (property `ToolTipText`) but I found no way to add a title. In class `ToolTip` there is a property `ToolTipTitle` but it is neither accessible from the `DataGridViewCell` object, nor usable via the underlying `ToolTip` used by the `DataGridView`. I tried either to set it in the `CellValueNeeded` and in the `CellToolTipTextNeeded` events but nothing...

My next try was to directly set the `ToolTip` to the `DataGridViewCell` but I rapidly discovered that such a cell was not inherited from `Control`... :-(

I succeeded to display a titled tool tip by calling `ToolTip::Show()` but I "was told" that we should never call `ToolTip::Show()` and let the framework do the job.

Is there something I missed or fully handling the tool tip by hand is my only solution?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the way I found is to catch the event `CellMouseEnter` then display a real tooltip. I compute the position of the tooltip using the location of the mouse when the event is fired. I use `Tooltip::Show(...)`.

I must also prevent the normal tooltip managed by the `DataGridView` by setting its property `ShowCellTooltip = false`.

I also catch the event `CellMouseLeave` to hide the tooltip if I the cursor leaves the cell before the tooltip vanishes.